# Problem with FPS Controller - weapon collision (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I implemented FPSController from Standard Assets into my little 3D maze game. Controller has a camera as his child object and collides with the environment nicely. However, I want to add a weapon to my game and stick it to the player so I  placed a weapon prefab as a child of my camera. The problem is, the weapon goes through walls even tho it has a collider. When I unparent it and give it a Rigidbody of its own, the weapon collides with other objects normally. If I give it a Rigidbody while parented (disabled collision between player and weapon before), it starts rotating and floating around after collision with walls. If I try to freeze rotation and position, it doesn't collide at all again. I tried creating another collider as part of my FPSController but doesn't collide with anything again. I even tried to unparent it and make a "ObjectFollowOtherObject" script but no collision again. No idea how to solve this, tried searching in other topics but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So, for some reason, I couldn't find this solution before but I found it now and this fixed it for me: https://youtu.be/uMtse2rN-zU

Apparently, this is a camera clipping problem and not a collision problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can just use two cameras one rendering only weapons and other one rendering rendering everything but the weapon and combine them together

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).